# Flutter error: Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

My android emulator run successfully, and before a project clone from github my flutter project worked fine. But when I clone a project after that show me a error, when I run my project, error like this:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
D:\Flutter project\Practice\flutter_app_demo\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] D:\Flutter project\Practice\flutter_app_demo\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] D:\Flutter project\Practice\flutter_app_demo\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I don't know why show error like this.

Any suggestion Please.

Comment: Did you try changing the sdk: minSdkVersion from 16 to 23, in your build.grandle file?

Comment: I have changed this version, but still show me same error

Answer (score 0):

its seems you have an error in your AndroidManifest.xml if you making any change in this file you should check it or put this file here to taking look at it